# In SSRS how can I change 1 type of border style without affecting the others when multiple cells with different styles are selected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Here's my problem. In a SSRS 2008 Tablix I have a block of cells that have different border styles already set (eg the top cell has a solid border on top, the bottom cell has a solid border on the bottom and all the others nothing). When selecting a group of cells, as soon as one of the cells has a different value for a parameter, the parameter value goes blank.

That's usually not a problem, but in the case of multi-value parameters (eg. size, location, borders) the different values cannot be expanded by pressing the + sign.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXJ7D.png

vs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP9RP.png

So, if I want to change a value I have to enter all the values separated by commas on the "header" of that property. By doing that I am forced to set values for all of the sub-values, even though I want to change just one of them. I tried leaving the values as blank hoping it would keep the current value but it does not seem to work.

Anyone knows how to achieve this? I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bug in Report Designer (or Report Builder)

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading the report as an RDL file and edit it directly in a text editor.
Then re-upload it when you're done.